# Torres de Hanoi mostrar por pantalla las torres

Tags: python

Llevo ya un tiempo intentando ver como hacer para mostrar las torres de Hanoi tras cada movimiento dado por el algoritmo pero lo que pasa con mi código es que muestra las torres de forma desordenada y no sé el como hacer para que se muestren ordenas.
El 3 representa al disco más grande y el 1 el más pequeño.

```
def moverHanoi(numeroDiscos,torreOrigen,torreAuxiliar,torreDestino):
    if(numeroDiscos == 1):
        torreDestino.append(torreOrigen.pop())
        #Mostrar las torres
        print("\n")
        print (torreOrigen)
        print (torreAuxiliar)
        print (torreDestino)
        print("\n")

    else:
        moverHanoi(numeroDiscos-1,torreOrigen,torreDestino,torreAuxiliar)
        torreDestino.append(torreOrigen.pop())
        #Mostrar las torres
        print("\n")
        print (torreOrigen)
        print (torreDestino)
        print (torreAuxiliar)
        print("\n")
        moverHanoi(numeroDiscos-1,torreAuxiliar,torreOrigen,torreDestino)
        
def hanoi(numeroDiscos):
    torreOrigen=[]
    torreAuxiliar=[]
    torreDestino=[]
    #Colocar los discos en torreOrigen
    i = numeroDiscos
    while (i>0):
        torreOrigen.append(i)
        i = i -1
    #Mostrar las torres inicialmente
    print("\n")    
    print (torreOrigen)
    print (torreAuxiliar)
    print (torreDestino)
    print("\n") 
    moverHanoi(numeroDiscos,torreOrigen,torreAuxiliar,torreDestino)

hanoi(3)
```

Y lo que se muestra por pantalla es esto:

```
[3, 2, 1]  [3,2]   [3]  []     []     [2]  []     []
[]         []      [2]  [3]    [3]    [3]  [3,2]  []
[]         [1]     [1]  [2,1]  [2,1]  [1]  [1]    [3,2,1]
```

y la forma correcta deberia ser:
[image: Forma correcta de mostrar las torres]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que la dificultad surge de que vas intercambiando las posiciones de las torres, y por lo tanto, las imprimes en distinto orden según a que profundidad de `moverHanoi` te encuentres.

Modifique tu programa para asignar las torres a variables globales para efectos de impresión y agregue una función que siempre las imprime en el mismo orden.

```
tO = None
tA = None
tD = None

def mostrarTorres():
    print(tO, tA, tD)

def moverHanoi(numeroDiscos, torreOrigen, torreAuxiliar, torreDestino):
    if (numeroDiscos == 1):
        torreDestino.append(torreOrigen.pop())
        mostrarTorres()
    else:
        moverHanoi(numeroDiscos - 1, torreOrigen, torreDestino, torreAuxiliar)
        torreDestino.append(torreOrigen.pop())
        mostrarTorres()
        moverHanoi(numeroDiscos - 1, torreAuxiliar, torreOrigen, torreDestino)


def hanoi(numeroDiscos):
    global tA, tD, tO

    torreOrigen = []
    torreAuxiliar = []
    torreDestino = []
    tA = torreAuxiliar
    tD = torreDestino
    tO = torreOrigen
    # Colocar los discos en torreOrigen
    i = numeroDiscos
    while (i > 0):
        torreOrigen.append(i)
        i = i - 1
    # Mostrar las torres inicialmente
    mostrarTorres()
    moverHanoi(numeroDiscos, torreOrigen, torreAuxiliar, torreDestino)


hanoi(3)
```

muestra las torres siempre en el mismo orden: origen, auxiliar, destino.

```
[3, 2, 1] [] []
[3, 2] [] [1]
[3] [2] [1]
[3] [2, 1] []
[] [2, 1] [3]
[1] [2] [3]
[1] [] [3, 2]
[] [] [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sé me hubiese ocurrido utilizar una variable global.